Concatenate strings and numbers in google sheets
Good day,
I have a series of numbers and a keyword wherein I need to concatenate them in a single cell.
For example:
I have a keyword "Cloud" on cell A1 - A10, while on B1 - B10 I have a number 001 - 010 (Formatted as Custom number format "000"). If i concatenate them on C1-C10, the result is Cloud1. The output that I need to see is Cloud001, Cloud002 and so forth. Tried to Change the format of Column C to String and it shows the same result. By the way, i need it in able for me to sort them out fast. Appreciate your input in this matter. Thank you guys.
I have a keyword "Cloud" on cell A1 - A10, while on B1 - B10 I have a number 001 - 010 (Formatted as Custom number format "000"). If i concatenate them on C1-C10, the result is Cloud1. The output that I need to see is Cloud001, Cloud002 and so forth. Tried to Change the format of Column C to String and it shows the same result. By the way, i need it in able for me to sort them out fast.


You may try this single formula in Cell_C1:
=arrayformula(A1:A10&text(B1:B10,"000"))



You can use this formula, which add padding with zeros untill the number in b is 3 ciphers.
=CONCATENATE(A1, REPT("0", 3-LEN(B1)), B1)

Which will give this result:


@Blindspots The first suggestion with the "&" for CONCATENATE will work indeed. But your second approach is faulty, as Cloud + 001 and Cloud + 010 would both result in Cloud001.
The first suggestion you made is more readable and I would actually prefer that - so gave you an upvote none the less.

Oops. Corrected. Should have been RIGHT, not LEFT (sorry).    =A1&RIGHT("00"&B1,3)  Array version =INDEX(A1:A10&RIGHT("00"&B1:B10,3)

No need to upvote my comments except to acknowledge them.  If you like you can incorporate it into your answer, if not np.  I remove my comments once acknowledged in any case as they are not for the world, just for you.

try:
=INDEX(A1:A10&TO_TEXT(B1:B10))


sorted:
=SORT(A1:A10&TO_TEXT(B1:B10))


or just skip helper columns (if this is a generation):
=INDEX("Cloud"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(10), "000"))


